# IndexMissingException while searching store in Elastic Search

Tags: java, testing, junit, elasticsearch, integration-testing

I am writing some tests to Search documents in ElasticSearch but I am receiving an IndexMissingException [indexed_store_detail] missing.I create a Node inside my tests.At the start of the test I insert the document and when I make the following call I get the exception.

```
SearchResponse response = getClient()
            .prepareSearch(getIndexNameV2(), getIndexTypeV2())
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.idsQuery().addIds("1"))
            .execute().actionGet();
```

This is weird because the GetResponse works fine with the same and literally the same code.What could be wrong ?

```
GetResponse response = getClient().prepareGet(getIndexNameV2(), getIndexTypeV2(),"1")
            .execute().actionGet();

org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexMissingException: [indexed_store_detail] missing
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData.convertFromWildcards(MetaData.java:648)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData.concreteIndices(MetaData.java:559)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:112)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:61)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:58)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:48)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:61)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:43)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:61)
at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.execute(NodeClient.java:92)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.search(AbstractClient.java:214)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder.doExecute(SearchRequestBuilder.java:841)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:62)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:57)
at com.paypal.demandgen.places.search.server.search.TestElasticSearchResponseParserV3toV1.parsePassesForSearchResponse(TestElasticSearchResponseParserV3toV1.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Does it work after the first run? Searching is _not_ real time in Elasticsearch. It's _near real time_. If you were typing it all in on the command line (e.g., using `curl`), then it would probably look like it was real time. However, the time between executing commands will be much faster, so I expect that you either mistyped the index name (hence the 404-like exception), or you are searching for the response too fast. Honestly though, I suspect the former more than the ladder because the index's existence will appear _before_ the document is actually searchable, but you can still be faster.

Comment: No it does not work after the first run.It fails each time a prepareSearch Request but passes everytime for the prepareGet request

Comment: Since these are being performed by JUnit, it is also possible that these queries are being done in parallel (or very close to it), which would probably make this happen. Make sure that the indexing has actually happened, probably in a `@BeforeClass` and possibly with a forced delay. Can we see the indexing code (and how it interacts with the search code)?

Comment: There is only one test case.When I said the GetResponse works and SearchResponse does not I comment out the one not being used

Comment: `GetResponse`s are not the same as searching, as they just perform a lookup to fetch the record (assuming it exists), which should exist _immediately_ after indexing. `SearchResponse`s require that the document has been analyzed before it will return them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the mistake was .It should have been called in the following fashion.It was a learning for me

```
getClient() .prepareSearch(getIndexNameV2()).getType(getIndexTypeV2())
```

Comment: Ah ha! Good catch, I suppose `indexed_store_detail` is the `type` rather than the `index`. That is a slightly annoying difference between the search and get APIs.